# PHP - Codeigniter - Redirect Loop

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, redirect, codeigniter-2

Whenever I visit my website at `[website].com` the page will continuously redirect until the browser shows `This webpage has a redirect loop`.

**BUT**

When I visit `[website].com/[controller]` then everything works fine.

---

Not all of this may be relevant but I will list as much information as I can/know.

The default controller in `routes.php` is `welcome`

The welcome controller:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Welcome extends CI_Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        // Testing: Does not reach this die statement
        die('error');
        //$this->load->view('public/welcome');
    }
}
```

.htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

---

### Update

---

This might be an(the) issue but I have the `[website].com` domain pointing to a sub folder `/public_html/[website].com/` where I have my Codeigniter folder structure as well as `index.php` and `.htaccess`

Comment: Nothing wrong here. Open your page in Firebug and see what it shows in Net tab.

Comment: Chrome Developer Tool shows a bunch of `302 Found`'s for `[website].com`. The `Initiator` listed as `http://[website].com Redirect`

Comment: Is apache/web server setup to properly even display the correct folder? This might be prior to CI.  Also you could try enabling debug log and see if controller is loaded at all, and if it is even CI causing this issue.

Comment: How do you point `website.com` to `/public_html/[website].com/`?

Comment: @anubhava Its through Netfirms...

Comment: @Jakub I don't have access to the webserver setup :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So with a little debugging I figured out that it wasn't any `.htaccess` file that was messing around with redirecting. It was actually the CodeIgniter Framework. And to be more specific, a [`Hook`](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/hooks.html).

A problem with the hook made it constantly redirect to `[website].com` which tried to access the default controller `welcome` ... and then redirect, so on and so forth.

Oh, the little things!

Thanks for everyone's help!

Comment: @VipulHadiya I don't remember how but I had to fix a code error that kept redirecting improperly. If you are having problems, I would suggest posting your own question. Stackoverflow is a great community for solving all your problems! :)

Answer (score 1):

My `.htaccess` looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

My `routes.php` looks like this:

```
$route["default_controller"] = "welcome";
$route["404_override"] = "";
```

My controller is in this path:

> /codeigniter/2.1.4/application/controllers/Welcome.php

I am no `.htaccess` wiz but can you try making yours match mine?

**Update:**

Can you take `.htacess` completely out of the equation for a minute (either by moving, renaming, or deleting the contents of the file) and try visiting these URLs?

`http://www.your-website.com/index.php`

or

`http://www.your-website.com/index.php/welcome`

or

`http://www.your-website.com/index.php/welcome/index`

Comment: I still get a redirect loop when I visit `[website].com` ... I don't know what's going on! :(

Comment: Please see **`Update:`** section

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this issue by setting the value of "$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']" to "TRUE"
In my case it’s due to sanitizing of cookie values by security class.
But Encryption of cookie data solves the problem.